# Start RAW audio file from the middle on MediaPlayer

Tags: android

This should be a very straightfoward awnser, but I still can't find a reliable solution. Say I have a `.mp3` on the `raw` resource folder, and I want to start playing it from the middle... So I use the `MediaPlayer` API and make a method that looks something like this:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.blablabla);
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                            mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration() / 2);
                        }
                    });
```

This in theory should work, but it always starts the music from start. Even putting the line `mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration() / 2);` before the start or out of the Listener doesn't solve my problem. What exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onPrepared` the stream size is probably not known, so `getDuration` returns 0, most likely. You need to check the duration when the size is known - `onVideoSizeChanged`() is probably the right place.